# What causes PC's to be unable to read certain other PC's shared folders even though other devices can read them?

Tags: domain, windows-server-2012-r2, file-sharing

I have a private domain where folders are shared to EVERYONE (temporarily during setup).  All PC's can click into any other PC in File Explorer's Network list, but one specific PC can't connect to the shared folders on 2 other PC's, even though the other 2 PC's can connect back to that PC that can't connect.

All other devices on the network can read and be read, just this one PC can't read 2 specific PC's.

The only difference I could see is that these 3 PC's all have IP's assigned by DHCP, but I feel certain there are other more likely issues.

**Added after initial post:**

So this morning I tried again to connect from the PC that couldn't contact the other 2 PC's.  The connection was established with 1 of the PC's, but only after an exceptionally long search before the credentials screen popped up.  The 2nd PC still cannot be reached.

I turned on 'IP address' in the Windows Explorer detail listing and noticed that this PC that is having trouble connecting to other PC's displays 127.0.0.1.  Also, many of the devices on the network do not even display with an IP.  I don't know where that display value comes from and wondered if it has any bearing on the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while there are likely many reasons, I thought I should post what was my problem.  My DNS records were messed up after I changed the IP's ([see this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/702474/how-do-i-recover-permissions-after-changing-the-lan-addresses-of-a-network)).  When I corrected the Host (A) records for each affected destination PC, then an immediate connection was established.

My thanks to joeqwerty for his comment at the post linked just above:

"Verify that all hosts are using the correct network address and subnet mask. Then verify that you've got your DC's configured correctly for DNS; each DC should use it's "partner" DC for primary DNS and it's own ip address for secondary DNS and 127.0.0.1 for tertiary DNS. Then verify that the A records for the DC's reflect their new ip addresses in your AD DNS zone. Verify that all domain joined computers are only using the two DC's for DNS. –  joeqwerty"

These comments are a nice checklist for things to look at, and his suggestion to verify the A records reflecting proper IP's brought me to the problem.

Thanks Joe.